# If exists update else insert in one query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have simple table like this:

```
+----------+---------------+-------------+
| ID (int) | KEY (varchar) | VALUE (int) |
+----------+---------------+-------------+
|        1 | asdf          |         100 |
|        2 | fdsa          |         321 |
|        3 | ecda          |         211 |
+----------+---------------+-------------+
```

and I want to update row where `KEY = 'something'` but if there is no row where `KEY = 'something'` I want to `INSERT` new row:

```
+----------+---------------+-------------+
| ID (int) | KEY (varchar) | VALUE (int) |
+----------+---------------+-------------+
|        1 | asdf          |         100 |
|        2 | fdsa          |         321 |
|        3 | ecda          |         211 |
|        4 | something     |         200 |
+----------+---------------+-------------+
```

Is it possible in only one query?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can utilize `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

```
INSERT INTO yourtable (`id`, `key`, `value`) VALUES (4, 'something', 200)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `value` = 200;
```

`key` column should have UNIQUE index on it

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce362/1)**

Answer (score 6):

Yes, that's pretty simple.

This is what you are looking for:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Column1='SomeValue')
    UPDATE Table1 SET (...) WHERE Column1='SomeValue'
ELSE
    INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (...)
```