# If exists update else insert on basis of WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This query is updating DB table by using more than one checks in where. The problem is i want to insert all missing rows against consultant id's in that week and day.

```
UPDATE agenda
SET comments = 1
WHERE  term_id = 31
  AND day IN ( 1, 3 )
  AND week IN ( 1, 3, 4 )
  AND consultant_id IN ( 1, 2, 3)
```

For example There is a row having `consultant_id=3 and week=1 which has no day=2` in the database, I want to insert new row having `consultant_id=3 ,week=1, day=2 and comments=1`.
In case the row with  `consultant_id=3 ,week=1, day=2 exist` it should simply update comments.

What i tried  to use `ON DUPLICATE KEY` [this related ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16380027/1564818)
But the problem is I have all `consultant_id`'s, `week`'s and `day`'s in an array and I have to update comments on the basis of these three.

Will really appreciate any help.

Comment: Post sample data and desired output in a tabular form. It might help to get your answer faster.

Comment: ok @peterm, will add some tabular data.

Comment: ... easiest (for testing) when provided as `CREATE TABLE ....` and `INSERT INTO ...` statements

Comment: @mansoor Do you need help with your question?

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be in one query?

A solution could be (pseudocode):

```
$result = query("UPDATE agenda
    SET comments = 1
    WHERE  term_id = 31
       AND day IN ( 1, 3 )
       AND week IN ( 1, 3, 4 )
       AND consultant_id IN ( 1, 2, 3) ");
if (affected_rows($result) == 0) {
  // do insert query
}
```

Comment: how can i know which rows still remain to insert?

Comment: Well, the ones that weren't in your `WHERE` clause. Hard to say without knowing some background.

Answer (score -1):

I think your query is right, but if the example you gave reflected your table the query will not update anything.

You want update the table with `consultant_id=3 ,week=1, day=2 and comments=1`.

In your query you put this statement  `AND day IN ( 1, 3 )`
which means you limit the days to be only one and three. So `day=2` won't satisfy the condition, which means the update won't work.

If you want to add new record use `insert` statement instead.

Comment: Actually, that is my question. How can i handle this situation, If record is not present to update??